# Is this the right way to write Sailor Pluto in Japanese?

Tags: katakana, typesetting

[image]

I'm in the middle of my painting and I don't want the name to be wrong cause the whole thing takes me days. Please help if you can :)

Comment: This is a question about Japanese language that has basically nothing to do with anime or manga. Such questions are off-topic here as per https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69. With that said, the correct writing is セーラープルート. Without the [chōonpu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%8Donpu) it is not correct.

Comment: I'm going to move this over to Japanese.SE, though they may end up closing this and rejecting the migration.

Answer (score 8):

No, this looks horribly odd to me. This is as bad and cryptographic as this:

[image]

Virtually everyone who is fluent in Japanese *will* misread this at first sight, although perhaps most will eventually notice what is the intended meaning if her picture were with this.

This is how the characters should normally be aligned in case you didn't know:

[image]

As a design work, you can move the positions of the characters like this while maintaining readability:

[image]

Real-world good examples would be [this](http://www.smashbros.com/jp/) and [this](http://g-tekketsu.com/). But don't let those vertical bars come completely beside the preceding characters.

Comment: 外国人の意見です。最初の画像厳しすぎるのですか？確かに長音符はそんな形しないはずだけど、ぼくはただそれと狭い所に入れ込んだ文字だと思った

Comment: Yes long-vowel marks can be distorted like that as long as they are placed in the right position. The main problem is the positions.

Comment: So they should be aligned with the previous kana (or even kanji in some situations), right?

Comment: In vertical writings characters are read top to bottom, *right to left*. But in the OP's picture it's top to bottom, *left to right*. (That's why I used the *bottom-to-top* order in my first picture)

Comment: Ok I think I can see where you're coming from. I just thought that moving the long vowel marks between the original image and your last image wouldn't make such a big difference. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Although winding, my last picture can be called a single (top-to-bottom) vertical line because subsequent characters are always lower. That's a big difference to me.

Comment: +1 good Japanese typography tutorial :)

Answer (score 3):

As Logan mentions in the comments, your sketch seems to be missing the `ー` ([chouonpu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%8Donpu)). It's important and should not be omitted (though it sometimes happens in informal writing). Note that in vertical writing it is [also written vertically](https://www.slideshare.net/Accura/vertical-layout-in-katakana).

Comment: This, I didn't even notice it and thought it was a weird bracket on the side.

Answer (score 2):

If those vertical bars with a concave outline are supposed to be 「ー」,  then this is technically correct if the reader can guess how they should be read.

Usually vertical writing is top-to-down and right-to-left, though, so this looks as weird as

```
wr
it
ing
```

(okay you got the point) like this.

Here is an example of how (manga) sound effects are normally written:

[image: manga sfx]

> - どきっ
> - ワーッ
> - ザー
> - ドドーン
> - ざわざわ
> - ガキィンッ